# rod-cutting by dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm

In the CLRS Introduction to Algorithms, for the rod-cutting problem during introducing the dynamic programming, there is a paragraph saying that

> In a related, but slightly simpler, way to arrange a recursive
>   structure for the rodcutting problem, we view a decomposition as
>   consisting of a first piece of length i cut off the left-hand end, and
>   then a right-hand remainder of length n - i. Only the remainder, and
>   not the first piece, may be further divided.

Why is that true that we don't need to consider the decomposition of the first piece of length i cut off the left-hand end?

Thanks.

Comment: -1, sorry. Your question is meaningless without some explanation of what "the rod-cutting problem during introducing the dynamic programming" is. I actually happen to have a copy of *Introduction to Algorithms* handy at the moment, but it's not reasonable to expect that everyone will.

Comment: (Addendum: I've now pulled out my copy, and I couldn't find the problem in question. I suspect that you have a different edition than I have.)

Answer (score 0):

The length of rod cut off the left-hand end is the piece that is cut to the length that is needed -- the use of the right-hand piece isn't decided yet and may be cut into smaller pieces.

Comment: Why is the length of the first piece is needed? Based on the description, whether or not decompose the first piece should give the same results, which means the DP will traverse all the possibilities, but it doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: @AmesISU There is an optimal decomposition.  That optimal decomposition will have a first piece of some size.  If we search through all possible combinations of first pieces+optimal decomposition of the rest, we *will* find that optimal decomposition.  Think of it as being like a complete search of a room.  You search by breaking the room up into sections then searching each section completely.  You don't worry while searching one section whether it *might* be somewhere else.  Your search pattern will cover that possibility eventually.